# Bufferedreader doesn't read the whole line at a time?

Tags: java, string, text-files, bufferedreader, readline

I'm using `BufferedReader` to read a text file line by line using `Bufferedreader.readLine()` but suddenly it doesn't read the whole line instead it reads only the first string only

Example: if the first line in the text file is:

```
[98.0,20.0,-65.0]  [103.0,20.0,-70.0] 5.0 [98.0,20.0,-70.0] ccw
```

And my code is:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path" + "arcs.txt"));
String Line = br.readLine();
System.out.println(Line):
```

The output will be:

```
[98.0,20.0,-65.0]
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: It could be a line endings issue. Maybe there is a `\n` in your file, and your reader does not break the line on that character. On the other hand, a `BufferedReader` looks for `\n`, `\r`, and `\r\n` as the line endings.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. Is it possible that there is some line separator character after that array which your editor doesn't show.

Comment: You could try reading the second line. If it starts with "[103.0,20.0, " then there is some kind of line separator in your "first line".

Comment: @RalfRenz yes i tried and that's what happened

Comment: I got the entire line on using the above snippet, as others. Check for CTRL-M characters and try printing the file content with line breaks `cat -A /tmp/testing.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BufferedReader` works internally as follows:

The InputSream or InputFile character stream will be buffered until an instance of `\n` (linefeed) or `\r` (carriage return) occures. Without the occurence of one of these two characters the `BufferedReader` is stuck in a while loop. An Exception to this case is, when the input character stream is closed. Therefore the only reasonable explanation why it's returning early must be, that there is some kind of line ending character after the first bit of the line. To make sure you catch everything in the file you can add a surrounding while loop.

**Example:**

```
// Please ignore the fact that I am using the System.in stream in this example.
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in) ))
  {

    String line;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // Read lines until null (EoF / End of File / End of Stream)
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
     {
       // append the line we just read to the StringBuilds buffer
       sb.append(line);
     }
    // Print the StringBuilders buffer as String.
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
  }
  catch ( IOException e )
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // Exception handling in general...
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The readLine() method of the buffer reader reads a string until it reaches a line seperator such as \n or \r. Your textfile must have these tokens after [98.0,20.0,-65.0].